# If null or empty means it will take some values in condition mvc2

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, view

I want to show up if the value is empty it will show some values

**code is**

```
 <p>
        <strong>Preferred Industry:</strong>
        <%Obj.Models.JobPreferredIndustry ji = new Obj.Models.JobPreferredIndustry(); %>
        <%if (ji.IndustryId!=0)
          { %>
        <% foreach (Obj.Models.JobPreferredIndustry jpi in Model.JobPreferredIndustries)
           { %>

              <% if (jpi.IndustryId != null)
                 { %>
                <%:jpi.Industry.Name%>
            <%}
                 else
                 { %>
               <%:jpi.IndustryId == null ? "Any" : jpi.Industry.Name%>
            <% } %>
            <% } %>
      <%} else { %>
        <%:"Any"%>
      <% } %>
    </p>
```

But this above code always showing **"Any"** only.. Is any mistake i did? please help me?

Answer (score 0):

`<%Obj.Models.JobPreferredIndustry ji = new Obj.Models.JobPreferredIndustry(); %>`
You created new `ji` then it's always null so your result always "Any".
Try create a ActionResult that return value of JobPreferredIndustry, may be like this :
`public ActionResult PreferredIndustry(){
return View("YourView",dbo.JobPreferredIndustry.ToList());
}`
 then in your View :
`<% foreach ( var item in Model.JobPreferredIndustry ) { %>
//do your code here
<% } %>`